# Swift when appending custom class to array all previous values overwritten

Tags: arrays, swift, append, overwrite

I have a custom class called Subject, which I am trying to initialize versions of and append to a array, however when I append one to a array it overwrites all the Subjects all ready in there. For example this code

```
var things:[Subject] = []
    things.append(Subject(initName: "1", initTeacher: "1", initClassroom: "1"))
    things.append(Subject(initName: "2", initTeacher: "2", initClassroom: "2"))
    print(things[0].name)
    print(things[1].name)
```

is printing `Optional("2") Optional("2")` when it should be printing `'Optional("1") Optional("2")'`

This is the code for my custom class

```
class Subject: NSManagedObject{

var name: String?
var teacher: String?
var classroom: String?

init(initName: String, initTeacher: String, initClassroom: String){
    name = initName
    teacher = initTeacher
    classroom = initClassroom
}

func save() -> Bool{
    if(name == "" || teacher == "" || classroom == ""){
        return false
    }else{

        let appDelgate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelgate?.managedObjectContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Subject", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext!)
        let subject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        subject.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        subject.setValue(teacher, forKey: "teacher")
        subject.setValue(classroom, forKey: "classroom")

        do{
            try managedContext?.save()
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print("Failed because of \(error)")
        }

        return true
    }
}

func edit(newName: String, newTeacher: String, newClassroom: String) -> Bool{
    let appDelgate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelgate?.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Subject")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name!)
    do{
        let fetchResults = try managedContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        let editingSubject = fetchResults![0] as! NSManagedObject

        editingSubject.setValue(newName, forKey: "name")
        editingSubject.setValue(newTeacher, forKey: "teacher")
        editingSubject.setValue(newClassroom, forKey: "classroom")

        do{
            try managedContext?.save()
            return true
        }catch{
            return false
        }
    }catch{
        return false
    }
}}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: so the code you show exhibits the problem or no? show how you're testing the contents of the array. why are you creating an object that isn't used in the code you show?

Comment: @Wain The problem is that when appending to the array for a second time the first value in the array is being overwritten by the second. I can see this as when I run 'print(array[0].name)' the first time its prints 'History', while the second time it prints Spanish. And which object are you referring to that is not used